# How to define Mock Hadley Cell in mathematical modeling?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am computing a force term in which one component is $F_{ext}$. To define this, the following content given in the paper.

**To capture the possible large-scale effects on precipitation clusters, we prescribe a mock cell : with a spatially varying flux field that has positive values near the domain center and negative values near the domain boundaries. This structure is introduced as a meridionally varying external flux term $F_{ext}$ with zero domain mean.**

The given domain is a rectangle of the length and width is 1 Km.

Can anyone please help me to define this function?

Do I only need to define a continuous function whose values near the centre are positive and on the boundaries are negative?

Comment: the field in a Hadley cell should be circulating, so it should have divergence zero; you could take the curl of any function of the radial coordinate.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I need to define a $F_{ext}$ as a scalar function of two variables. Curl is an operator between two vectors. Can we define Hadley cell as a scalar function?